# Angular 2 Validator pattern

Tags: regex, angular, pattern-matching

I tried to implement a pattern validator with a built in validator in angular. I wanted to use this patter: `/\S+/g` but it didn't work because angular overwrites my pattern in its function [You can see it here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/common/src/forms/validators.ts#L82) 
Why do they put the ^ and a $ at the beginning and the end of the string? Should I use a custom validator instead the built in? Is it a bug or working as expected?

Here is a plunkrhttp://plnkr.co/edit/OHrUitqUnhIYxsraby7J

Comment: The anchors are only added to a *string* pattern. If you pass a regex object (as a string), no anchors will be added. Also, you cannot use `/g` in the ng-pattern regex. Could you share a fiddle with your validator?

Comment: I have updated. [Here it is](http://plnkr.co/edit/OHrUitqUnhIYxsraby7J)

Comment: Ok, so, it means that the validator does not allow a regex object like string. Since you want to require at least one non-whitespace char, why not use [`".*\\S.*"`](http://plnkr.co/edit/mnGttywNdu5nHFDCmEyC?p=preview)?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Put it in an anser and I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this validator does not allow a regex literal to be passed. You need to make sure you match the *whole* string. So, *if you plan to require the string to have at least one non-whitespace character*, use

```
".*\\S.*"
```

See the [updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mnGttywNdu5nHFDCmEyC?p=preview).